# How to count how many fields in a JObject that are set with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

So I need to calculate how many fields in a JObject has a value that is not null or whitespace. I came up with the solution below that works fine. However, I am wondering if there is a way to do it with a fancy one-liner in LINQ instead?

```
  JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(@"{
    ""Name"":""Nisse"" ,
    ""Address"":""Road1"",
    ""Zip"":"""",
    }");

    var counter = 0;
    foreach (var x in jObject)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value.ToString()))
            counter++;
    }

    //Counter is now 2
```

Comment: Your solution only works for one level of hierarchy, is that all you are concerned with?

Comment: can you please try out solution

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, one level is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below check each property and return you not empty properties

```
jObject.Children().AsEnumerable().ToList()
.Count(t=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( t.Values().ToList()[0].ToString()))
```

Note : this code is based on the object structure provided in question.

Comment: This seems to work! Resharper actually suggested making it even shorter, like this:

Object.Children()
                .AsEnumerable().Count(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Values().ToList()[0].ToString()));

Comment: @nisse12 - that correct you can use resharper one version - updated my answer according to that

Answer (score 0):

You could use `int counter = jObject.Children().Count(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(((JProperty)c).Value.ToString()));`, but see for yourself if that is more readable.